# How to set property of child of child(or nth child) component in Angular 5

Tags: angular

How can I set property of child of child(or nth level child) component from parent in Angular 5 without creating intermediate variables. For example lets say I've child component as shown below.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child11',
  template: '<p><br/> child11 works!<br/> Name is {{name}}</p>',
  styleUrls: ['./child11.component.css']
})
export class Child11Component implements OnInit {

  @Input() name: string;
  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Let us say I've parent of child11 is child1 as shown below

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child1',
  template: '<p>child1 works!<app-child11 name="Karthik"></app-child11></p>',
  styleUrls: ['./child1.component.css']
})
export class Child1Component implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

And the parent component as shown belown

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '<div><app-child1></app-child1></div>',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}
```

Now how can I modify template of app-root such that I can directly set the name value of child11 in app-root, without introducing variable in Child1 that propagates to AppComponent?

Comment: im not sure you can, theres child-parent events and things you can use but im not sure on child-grandparent

Comment: As a best practice, you should not change the child component value from the parent. Use Observables if you need to pass any value from parent to child

Comment: @Srigar by changing the values, im pretty sure they meant from `@Input()`'s

Comment: You could use a store to do that, but you probably need to think a bit more about your design. Is it a smart or dumb component, should it look for data to show by it self or have only input values.

Comment: @mast3rd3mon Yes I've used  child-parent events, but here its second case, you mentioned. Though this example modified simpler version, in my actual use case I've a library component in place of child11,  which I want to modify, hence I may not be able to use observable as well.

Answer (score -1):

If I wanted to do this , I would prefer to use binded component input instead of simple input.

The code that I prepared is.

app.component.ts

```
import { OnInit, Component, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child11',
  template: '<p><br/> child11 works!<br/> Name is {{name}}</p>',
  styleUrls: []
})
export class Child11Component implements OnInit {

  @Input() name: string;
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() { }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child1',
  template: '<p>child1 works!<app-child11 [name]="name"></app-child11></p>',
  styleUrls: []
})
export class Child1Component implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
  @Input() name: string;
  ngOnInit() { }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  name: string;
}
```

app.component.html

```
<p>child1 works!
    <app-child11 [name]="name"></app-child11>
</p>
<br>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name"/>
```

Now whatever you write inside input tag in app-root component will be reach to app-child11 and finally it will print there.

I hope it can help you.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I would not like to create any intermediate variable, I know I can propagate as you shown, thats exactly what I want to avoid.

Answer (score -2):

if you dont want creating intermediat variables you can create `Service` for example `ChildService`. [Service Guide](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services). Create `child$: Observable<any[]>` or `child$$: Subject<any[]>` and subscribe on `Child11Component`:

```
this.child$
    .filter(child => child.name === this.name)
    .subscribe(child => this.child = child);
```

Your `this.child` variable has necessary child.

Comment: I had thought of service, its not viable, I want to bind the property to life cycle of the component.

Comment: A service definitely sounds like the cleanest approach for this. Could you elaborate on what lifecycle events you need to respond to and why a service wont support your use case?